# Local optima in high-dimensional optimization

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, references, gradient-descent

I remember a theorem along the lines of

> In higher dimensional optimization problems, you are less likely to get
> stuck in local optima, because the more dimensions you have, the more likely you are
> to have saddle points rather than local optima

I heard this in the context of gradient descent algorithms and training neural networks, if that helps.

Now I am looking for a reference to read further on this. Any pointers for further literature/theorems/proofs would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is hard to conceive of any such statement being justifiable in such generality: what is the space of possible "problems" and what is the implied sense of "more likely"?  This reads like an expression of somebody's experience rather than being any kind of general rule.

Comment: Of course, if there's a theorem for this, it will be much more narrow. Sadly I don't if there is or how to find it, that's the whole point of my my question here.